# ¿Por que al obtener valor JSON de base de datos no se puede decodificar en PHP?

Tags: php

Utilizo la siguiente function para insertar un JSON string en mi base de datos:

```
$a_value = 1;
$b_value = 0;
$c_value = 1;

$feature = array("A" => $a_value,
                    "B" => $b_value,
                    "C" => $c_value,
                );

$featureJson = json_encode($feature);
```

Obtengo esto

```
{"A":"1","B":"0","C":"1"}
```

Seguido en otra parte de mi sistema uso esto para obtenerlo

```
$queryDeEjemplo = SELECT * FROM features WHERE id = 1
$json = $stmt->fetch();
// Resultado: string "{"A":"1","B":"0","C":"1"}"
$resultado = json_decode($json);
// Resultado: NULL
```

¿Por que ocurre esto?

Utilizo `MYSQL`.
El campo `feature` es de tipo `VARCHAR` de 500 caracteres.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu manejador de base de datos? ¿De qué **tipo de dato** estamos hablando, de un `VARCHAR`, de un dato del tipo JSON propiamente...? Son detalles importantes que deberías indicar en la pregunta.

Comment: No sé si sabes que MySQL tiene un tipo de datos [`JSON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). En tu caso, el problema es, creo yo, que en el `SELECT` estás trayendo todas las columnas, y entre ellas hay un dato que es `VARCHAR`, pero está guardado como si fuera un JSON, entonces al aplicar el `json_decode` se crea una información confusa. No he podido probarlo, pero me parece que es eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano revisando el valor de la consulta con JSONLINT me da error en las llaves que tiene el string "{"

Comment: El resultado de `$featureJson`, es un json válido: `{
 "A": "1",
 "B": "0",
 "C": "1"
}`. He probado a insertar ese valor en una `VARCHAR` de una tabla y la única forma de trabajarlo con `json_encode` como tú quieres es si selecciono solamente ese campo. Como te decía, al implicar todos los campos en la consulta, te crea un valor que no es correcto para decodificarlo como json.

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias por la ayuda, podrias colocar tu respuesta para darte positivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## El problema

El problema es que:

1. Estás seleccionado todas las columnas de la tabla: `SELECT * FROM features WHERE id = 1;`
2. Estás creando un array: `$json = $stmt->fetch();` Algo parecido a esto:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [persona_id] => 9
       [persona_nom] => {"A":"1","B":"0","C":"1"}
       [ciudad_id] => 12
   )
   ```
3. Estás tratando de aplicar `json_decode`  a ese array: `$resultado = json_decode($json);` [Cuando dicha función debe recibir como parámetro una cadena, no un array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

El resultado de ese procedimiento es el siguiente Warning:

> PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given

y obtienes un valor `NULL` porque el parámetro no se pudo decodificar al ser incorrecto.

## Las soluciones

### 1.

Dado que el *supuesto* JSON, (digo supuesto porque en realidad es un `VARCHAR` dentro del cual estás guardando una cadena en forma de JSON), se encuentra en una sola columna de esa tabla, puedes obtenerlo accediendo a los datos que hay en ese columna específicamente.

Por ejemplo:

```
$json = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$resultado = json_decode($json["persona_nom"]);
print_r($resultado);
```

Ahí tendrás en pantalla:

```
{"A":"1","B":"0","C":"1"}
```

### 2.

De todos modos, aquí el uso de `json_decode` es redundante, ya que, *supuestamente*, debería haber un json válido en la columna `VARCHAR`. De hecho, si tú haces esto:

```
print_r ($json["persona_nom"]);
```

El resultado es el mismo que si usaras `json_decode`:

```
{"A":"1","B":"0","C":"1"}
```

Y si ese valor debe ser recibido como un JSON válido en otra parte (una llamada Ajax, un servido REST etc), con que le pongas el header antes del `print_r` sería suficiente.

### 3. La mejor solución

Nada mejor que cuando te tratan como lo que eres. En ese sentido, MySQL permite usar un [tipo de dato `JSON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), quizá sea el más adecuado, si quieres almacenar objetos JSON en tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de la versión 5.7 de MySQL puedes almacenar JSON como lo harías en un archivo tradicional; lo único que requieres es crear el campo que va a almacenar dicha info del modo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE mi_tabla( 
   id INT,
   campo_json JSON NOT NULL,
   detalle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Notese que JSON en la 3ra linea del código anterior es el tipo de datos que almacena el campo.

Mas info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: estoy trabajando con PHP 5.6.3

Comment: @vaavDev te recomiendo actualizar ya que esto conlleva bastantes beneficios como por ejemplo este campo especial para este tipo de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema en lo siguiente:

1. Estaba obteniendo un array con los otros campos de la tabla.
2. Estaba tratando de convertir todo el array.
3. Luego solo consulte el campo, pero tampoco servia.
4. Prosegui a convertir el json a array, pero accediendo al valor, no tomando el array completo.

   ```
   $resultJson = $stmt->traerUnico();
   // array ["features"] => string {"A":"1","B":"0","C":"1"}
   $result = json_decode($resultJson["features"]);
   // object(stdClass)#7 ["A"] => 1, ["B"] => 2, ["C"] => 3
   ```